# sql statement for and or selection (access VBA)

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an SQL statement where i need to select an ID and date but will have 6 seperate columns to validate.

VBA:

```
strsql = "SELECT * FROM [Tbl_Master_Table] WHERE [IndexRepID] = '" & ID & "' AND [IndexStDtTm] = #" & today & "# OR [ProcRepID] = '" & ID & "' AND [ProcStDtTm] = #" & today & "# OR [UWRepID] = '" & ID & "' AND [UWStDtTm] = #" & today & "#"
```

SQL:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    [Tbl_Master_Table]
WHERE
    [IndexRepID] = ? -- ID
    AND
    [IndexStDtTm] = ? -- today
    OR
    [ProcRepID] = ? -- ID
    AND
    [ProcStDtTm] = ? -- today
    OR
    [UWRepID] = ? -- ID
    AND
    [UWStDtTm] = ? -- today
```

unfortunately it does not select any record. is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

HEREs the final outcome... it actually worked...

```
today1 = DateValue(Format(Now(), "mm dd, yyyy")) + 1 
ID = psid 
Me.Lst_MyDash_Today.RowSource = "" 

strsql = "SELECT * FROM [Tbl_Master_Table] WHERE ([IndexRepID] = '" & ID & "' AND [IndexStDtTm] >= #" & today & "# AND [IndexStDtTm] < #" & today1 & "#) OR [ProcRepID] = '" & ID & "' AND [ProcStDtTm] >= #" & today & "# AND [ProcStDtTm] < #" & today1 & "#" 'OR [UWRepID] = '" & ID & "' AND [UWStDtTm] >= #" & today & "# AND [UWStDtTm] < #" & today1 & "#"
```

Comment: here it is... SELECT * FROM [Tbl_Master_Table] WHERE [IndexRepID] = '11111' AND [IndexStDtTm] = #3/3/2015# OR [ProcRepID] = '11111' AND [ProcStDtTm] = #3/3/2015# OR [UWRepID] = '11111' AND [UWStDtTm] = #3/3/2015#

Comment: Tried to put the open and close parenthesis but still returning all values regardless of date

    SELECT * FROM [Tbl_Master_Table] WHERE ([IndexRepID] = '43514986' AND [IndexStDtTm] = #3/3/2015#) OR ([ProcRepID] = '43514986' AND [ProcStDtTm] = #3/3/2015#) OR ([UWRepID] = '43514986' AND [UWStDtTm] = #3/3/2015#)

Comment: Found the reason... Dates in the database are formatted mm dd yyyy + hh:mm:ss

Comment: @Anton Are dates stored as text, or using the actual `date` type?

Comment: date type sir what do you suggest?

Comment: used this:

today1 = DateValue(Format(Now(), "mm dd, yyyy")) + 1
    ID = psid
    
    Me.Lst_MyDash_Today.RowSource = ""
    
    strsql = "SELECT * FROM [Tbl_Master_Table] WHERE ([IndexRepID] = '" & ID & "' AND [IndexStDtTm] >= #" & today & "# AND [IndexStDtTm] < #" & today1 & "#) OR [ProcRepID] = '" & ID & "' AND [ProcStDtTm] >= #" & today & "# AND [ProcStDtTm] < #" & today1 & "#" 'OR [UWRepID] = '" & ID & "' AND [UWStDtTm] >= #" & today & "# AND [UWStDtTm] < #" & today1 & "#"

it actually worked...

Comment: @Anton please don't post code in comments, instead update your original question, and please format your code to make it readable before submitting.

Answer (score 0):

Before you the bit where you actually execute the statement try putting

```
Debug.Print strsql
cmd.execute
```

If you post the actual query we may be able to help more.

Answer (score 0):

```
today1 = DateValue(Format(Now(), "mm dd, yyyy")) + 1
ID = psid

Me.Lst_MyDash_Today.RowSource = ""

strsql = "SELECT * FROM [Tbl_Master_Table] WHERE ([IndexRepID] = '" & ID & "' AND [IndexStDtTm] >= #" & today & "# AND [IndexStDtTm] < #" & today1 & "#) OR [ProcRepID] = '" & ID & "' AND [ProcStDtTm] >= #" & today & "# AND [ProcStDtTm] < #" & today1 & "#" 'OR [UWRepID] = '" & ID & "' AND [UWStDtTm] >= #" & today & "# AND [UWStDtTm] < #" & today1 & "#"
```